# Apple Keynote renders poorly in PDF (when seen on IOS or printed)

Tags: pdf, rendering, keynote

Thanks for your help with this vexing problem.

We've got a Keynote presentation that uses the "picture frame" effect around images. It looks great (see below) with a nice drop shadow.

Export it to PDF and it still looks great on a Mac.

But print it on any printer or send that file to an iPhone 13 with the latest software, and the frame becomes a black and white border with artifacts.

Is this an unfixable bug? Are we missing something?

Truly appreciate any help or resources. Thanks.

Here's the original in Keynote:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/m2cok26rfw9l83f/BTW%20Wedding%20Cake%20Guide%20February%202022.key?dl=0

and here it is in IOS

https://www.dropbox.com/s/3vu2t04yskcilj5/96249.jpg?dl=0

the printout looks the same.

Comment: Thanks K J.... would switching to PAGES be worth the journey, or is there a better platform to ensure resilience going forward?

Comment: really appreciate the extra effort, thank you. I'm confident the art director isn't going to be happy about losing the frames and shadows--that's a key part of the exercise. But we'll persist, and yes, the individual pages to pngs might be a great way forward.